# swift package manager doesn't find KituraNet

Tags: swift-package-manager, kitura

I want to test Kitura, so I did

```
swift package init --type executable
```

I made a minimal Package.swift

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "project2",
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura.git", .upToNextMinor(from: "2.0.0")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/HeliumLogger.git", .upToNextMinor(from: "1.7.1")),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-StencilTemplateEngine", .upToNextMinor(from: "1.8.3"))
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "project2",
            dependencies: ["Kitura", "HeliumLogger", "KituraStencil"]),
        ]
)
```

when I run swift build, the Error Message is

```
'Kitura' /Users/myname/Documents/myname/project2/.build/checkouts/Kitura.git-6522211175291160341: error: product dependency 'KituraNet' not found
```

I happened to do the exactly same thing on my desktop at work and everything was fine. Does anyone see what I am missing here?

Comment: using .package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-StencilTemplateEngine", from: "1.8.3") of .package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-StencilTemplateEngine", .upToNextMinor(from: "1.8.3") made this work (other dependencies accordingly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a version mismatch. Try updating Kitura:

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura.git", .upToNextMinor(from: "2.3.0")),
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. I still do not understand why .package(url: "github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-StencilTemplateEngine";, from: "1.8.3") is working as well but .package(url: "github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-StencilTemplateEngine";, .upToNextMinor(from: "1.8.3") is not. (Mind the difference concerning the Version parameter. In one case it is a String (works) the other case it is an enum (did not work)).

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your Package.swift. My guess is that you needed a newer version of KituraNet than what Kitura 2.0 uses.

You asked for `.upToNextMinor(from: "2.0.0")`, which means it will *not* use Kitura 2.1 or later (the current version is 2.3).

To avoid these problems, I usually update my dependencies all at once, so they're contemporary.